# How to estimate a complex (imaginary) refractive index from absorbance?

Tags: optics

In order to perform some optical simulations using the program Lumerical, i need a material's wavelength-dependent refractive index.

The material is strongly absorbing in certain wavelengths (it is red!), and I have data on its absorbance spectra. However, I do not have data on the complex component of its refractive index.

Is there a way to estimate or calculate the complex component of the refractive index?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem actually has a well-known solution. Given a function that is analytic in the upper-half plane, there are specific relations between its real and imaginary components. The refractive index $n\left(\omega\right)$ is such a function. Specifically, let $n\left(\omega\right)=n_{\rm r}\left(\omega\right)+in_{\rm i}\left(\omega\right)$. Then

$$n_{\rm r}\left(\omega\right)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{n_{\rm i}\left(\omega^{\prime}\right)}{\omega^{\prime}-\omega}{\rm d}\omega^{\prime}$$

and

$$n_{\rm i}\left(\omega\right)=-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{n_{\rm r}\left(\omega^{\prime}\right)}{\omega^{\prime}-\omega}{\rm d}\omega^{\prime}$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the principal value of the integral. These are the **Kramers-Kronig relations**. You can read more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations).